# Do individuals over the world expect a social system to provide "peace and abundance"?

Tags: ethics, empiricism, liberalism

Ludwig von Mises believes that "in general, men the world over expect a social system to provide "peace and abundance."[sic] (from "Ludwig von Mises and the Justification of the Liberal Order", Baumgarth, quoted in https://oll.libertyfund.org/page/mises-major-writings)

Do we have empirical data supporting the idea that people over the world expect a social system to provide "peace and abundance"? Encompassing very various societies, from, say Italy, to Afghanistan, to the Philippines.

I know of one research supporting it, which concerns Japan (Miwa 2018).

> While Japanese voters highly prioritized economic stability and social order, Japanese political candidates tended to prioritize freedom and equality.

From one study to the other, "peace" and "abundance" might be translated into more precise or not 100% matching criteria, such as in the study above where "stable job and appropriate income" could be interpreted as a translation for "abundance".

Still, I understand "peace" as meaning "a society where the level of physical violence on a daily basis is low overall" and "abundance" as meaning "a society where people have relatively easy access to a relatively high quantity of material goods and services".

**Note:**

Voltaire held a different view:

> All men are born with a sufficiently violent liking for domination, wealth and pleasure, and with much taste for idleness; consequently, all men want their money and the wives or daughters of others, to be their master, to subject them to all their caprices, and to do nothing, or at least to do only very agreeable things. You see clearly that with these fine inclinations it is as impossible for men to be equal as it is impossible for two predicants or two professors of theology not to be jealous of each other. (Voltaire, Philosophical dictionary, ["Equality" article](https://history.hanover.edu/texts/voltaire/volequal.html)).

**References:**

Miwa, H. (2018). Value preferences and structures among Japanese voters and political candidates. *Japanese Political Science Review*, 4, 61-85.

Comment: why limit "peace" to the absence of physical violence? Bullying, insults, harassment, while not physical in nature are definitely not part of a peaceful society.

Comment: @armand because to me peace is still broadly understood as referring to the absence of physical violence. Most of human history is made of physical aggression, and relatively peaceful societies where people can start taking care about another, more subtile, kind of violence, are still new. IMK it was not until recently that debates started to raise concerning psychological harassment in developed countries

Comment: Dunno what you're asking... ppl don't like to get beaten up (or worse), ppl like assured food, shelter etc. Seems like a tautology to me. So what is the question really?

Comment: @Rushi I think it is an important issue, and in the case of Mises it is one important bit of his argumentation, so I think it deserves an empirical investigation. Thx for your comment.

Comment: @Rushi See also my comments under haxor789 answer

Comment: Well ok... but then I'm unable to tie those comments into the question above which still looks quite tautologous. [And Mises]

Comment: It does seem to amount to saying that people like things that are good for them. If they didn't, either we would say they were sick, or no one would be here at all.

Comment: See [Paternalistic Conservatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternalistic_conservatism).

Comment: If it doesn't, what's the point of it?

Answer (score 3):

On the [Cyrus Cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_Cylinder), arguably the first reciprocal commitment between a ruler and their people, Cyrus is portrayed as having been chosen by the chief Babylonian god Marduk to restore peace and order to the Babylonians.

The [Mandate of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandate_of_Heaven), was a Chinese philosophy that there was a right of rebellion against rulers who were unjust, or in the face of famine flood and widespread poverty.

The [Pax Romana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Romana) was inaugurated by a ceremony by Emperor Augustus of [Closing The Gates of Janus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Janus_(Roman_Forum)) symbolising that Rome was at peace, and creation of the [Ara Pacis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ara_Pacis), an altar to the Pax. The altar has a lower frieze depicting agricultural work meant to communicate the abundance and prosperity of the Peace. The monument and the significance of the Pax were the centrepiece of propaganda to ease the tensions around ending the Republic and formalising autocratic control, which had got Caesar assassinated. The concept led to many other examples of propaganda terms for justifying imperial control by peace, like the [Pax Britannica](https://Pax%20Britannica).

What I think is interesting about these examples, is that they covered systems of absolute rule, but show a discourse engaging with justification to the ruled why they should accept a ruler and their system. These formal expectations of justification by peace and plenty also covered huge areas of the world, and vast spans of time.

Genghis Khan's rule was justified by him beating the other contenders for leadership, and uniting the tribes. In the face of two very cold winters and associated risk of starvation, he was able to secure fealty with the promise successful wars. It's interesting that while mainly known for vast destruction, his empire also secured what is called the [Pax Mongolica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Mongolica), allowing the flourishing of trade, especially on the Silk Road. Trade generally produces far more wealth than conquest, and in the long run contentions between power blocks often come down to which has the stronger economy.

Religion has been a major source of state cohesion, like Pakistan meaning the "land of the spiritually pure and clean". Many states have been defined by and centred on commitment to religious rituals and traditions, not to delivery of peace or ptopserity. However, plagues and failed harvests were often interpreted as a state or ruler having lost favour with deity/ies, like the Plague of Thebes relating to the sins of Oeidipus, or the Black Death leading people to perform Bonfires of the Vanities.

Social Contract theory formalises the idea  of consent by the governed to the government. For Hobbes it was the need above all for rule-of-law that forced people to accept an absolute monarchy forever, to avoid life being nasty brutish and short. For Rousseau who had a more positive picture of the State of Nature, it meant a more reciprocal obligation between ruled and rulers, creating a right to rebel against rule which no longer served a people. As Thomas Jefferson summarised it, "When injustice becomes law, resistance becomes duty."

So peace and prosperity are not the only modes of expectation from government, it may be the promise of war and conquest that brings people together though likely for hostorically short eras, or it may be religious rites although it can be argued these tacitly expect peace and prosperity for those 'right with the gods'.

Arguably the beginning of human cooperation into states, involves getting a group to risk death fighting to preserve a system of organisation. So there have to be benefits, materially or psycholigically at least for those committed to military service, which historically was the basis of citizenship. I would relate that bioligically, evolutionarily, to the expectation that descendents will be better off with the system, even if the 'ultimate sacrifice' is required.

So while peace and prosperity are not absolute expectations for all people in all times, the expectation of benefit (at very least to the elite) is the basis of human cooperation, which we now describe as the Social Contract. Wars consume vast resources, and lives, so peace and prosperity generally coincide. There needs to be a good reason for war, like a radical disagreement in world view, or explicit threats to those who will fight.

In short, yes I think Mises statement is justified.

Comment: You tackled the question in a very nice and interesting way, and broadly made your point. I am not sure about the Gengis Khan example. How does in fit? It says that he was supported because he promised war.

Comment: "the expectation of benefit" which benefit?

Comment: Starckman: Genghis Khan was a counterexample. Others like the first Qin Emperor & Alexander the Great also offered more total war, than peace. Benefit generally means security, & prosperity - enough to fight & die to secure

Comment: I develop below haxo789 also other counter-examples, plus the one you give in your answer and comments, at the end we have many counter-examples to Mises claim....

Comment: @Starckman: But, they have enough motivation for a war-party, not enough for an Empire, or state.

Comment: I think that "a radical disagreement in world view" is not a reason for war, it is a reason to look very carefully at one's world view. (But then, everyone should be doing that anyway.) People should do things that are good for them.

Comment: @ScottRowe: I'd say it's maybe the best reason. Some act of war, a grievance, is just contingent events, which often soldiers going to war had no say in. Whereas, whether your descendents will prosper under ruthless capricious autocracy, or a system where they have participation in decusions, that really matters. Russia and Ukraine have almost the same language, essentially the same culture. But which view wins, will impact generations of people, whether they can creatively contribute or only tow the line, whether they can be themselves or have to hide from death squads for being different.

Comment: It is unfortunately true that when people are unreasonable, the solution ends up being to kill them. I guess humans get what they deserve. If they want a better world, they have to make themselves better.

Comment: “they have enough motivation for a war-party, not enough for an Empire, or state.” But in this question we are precisely discussing motivations, what people want, and there are many counter examples of people wanting war for seek of purity, rather than peace and prosperity

Comment: @ScottRowe: I heard it put also about Ukranians, that when a people refuse to accept not being free, their enemies can only leave them alone or kill them. Being 'unreasonable' in the face of oppression, brooking no compromise with it, is then the real basis of life without authoritarianism..

Comment: So it depends on your perspective, who is being unreasonable, which is why we still have these problems. But harm is not perspectival, it is objective. The definition of reason should be based on non-harming, as people have been saying for, oh, 5,000 years.

Comment: @ScottRowe: 'If we had the ability to make humanity less war-like, should we?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90783/if-we-had-the-ability-to-make-humanity-less-war-like-should-we/90793#90793

Answer (score 2):

> Ludwig von Mises believes that "in general, men the world over expect a social system to provide "peace and abundance."[sic] (from "Ludwig von Mises and the Justification of the Liberal Order", Baumgarth, quoted in https://oll.libertyfund.org/page/mises-major-writings)

This encodes essentially two claims a) that people around the world expect their social systems to do something and b) what it is that they expect them to.

Now with regards to b) that seems rather inoffensive. "Not dying or suffering" has a pretty universally high appeal for humans and really just for most living things in general. So without any empirical study I'd argue that's a pretty safe guess.

One possible angle of attack would be the meaning of "abundance". Like while most people would place the lack of scarcity rather high in their list of priorities "abundance" goes a lot further than that. And from the top of my head I could think of religious and other groups who prioritize an ascetic and frugal lifestyle which may or may not cause a conflict with the assertion of "abundance" (depending on the definition and the intent of that statement).

And with regards to a), that is what people expect from a social system, well that makes the tacit assumption that the social system is the result of voluntary cooperation, but there are plenty of social systems that aren't and people might not expect anything or at least nothing positive from them in the first place.

Comment: ""Not dying or suffering" has a pretty universally high appeal" Far-left revolutionary anarchists and communists hold the hate of the *bourgeois* to drive people into extreme political violence, far-right hold the hate of other-races to drive people into extreme political violence, same for the Christians during the Crusades, or the Islamist groups today. And there are some tribes like the Jivaro, the Yanomami, the Dani, which are extremely violent. What would be your account for these cases?

Comment: One could argue that the revolutionary leftists and the religious extremists promised a perfect land of peace and prosperity (or at least lack of scarcity). But we could respond to that that they first hold other values (social equality and moral purity) has primary over other values (peace and prosperity).

Comment: Concerning the far-right, I am not a specialist. Just saw that the nazis had the idea of "Lebensraum" which is like a promised land for their race, and is supposed to be like a Garden of Eden (so same thing as above). And then what about the tribes I mentioned

Comment: @Starckman You might want to use the sentence after the quote in your question, that is "What men expect from social cooperation is the satisfaction of as many of their most urgent wants as possible, and therefore they, for the most part, dispute about the type of social system that will serve this purpose."  As that seems to more illustrative of the argument and the thing that you disagree with, it also removes the ambiguity of abundance and whatnot.

Comment: @Starckman 2/ I'm not generally a fan of Mises and the Austrian School of Economics/Anarcho Capitalism/"Libertarianism" who wrap themselves in talks of liberty while often in effect shed any responsibility for their action and disregard how they squash the liberty of other people and you can argue that the way he formulates it makes it look like human relations are purely instrumental and meant for individual gains. While there are other factors in that. Like idk having children would for the longest part be a net negative if you looked at it just through the lens of material gains.

Comment: @Starckman 3/ That being said humans do have urgent needs that they need to fulfill and safety and subsistence are among the most urgent ones and cooperative social groups help in advancing these goals. Now to argue it's about the means rather than the goals, is both true and false. I unfortunately have to go so I need to continue that idea later :(

Comment: Ok but you did not really answered to the counter-examples I provided

Comment: @haxor789: Not from a 'genes-eye' perspective, which from a game-theory perspective on morality, probably should be considered the 'player', at root

Comment: @Starckman You could still frame these as quests for peace and prosperity, though with differences in long term vs short term, as well as differences in past, presence and future fulfillment of these needs. Often enough on an individual level these are reactions to real or perceived existential dread which is the opposite of peace and prosperity.

Comment: @Starckman 2/ Though it makes quite some difference if you obtain that prosperity through production and collaboration or through theft, domination/exploitation or even extinction of others. So same goals different means is true but also kind of an understatement.

Comment: @Starckman 3/ And technically the bourgeois isn't a group of people and isn't supposed to be hated it's a class in an economic model of society, where the blame isn't with them but with the material conditions that produces these classes. Otherwise it's not really a leftist idea, but more of a right wing idea of chauvinism of the working class. And "Lebensraum" is just the German word for "place to live" and is not some kind of utopia, but just the idea to settle eastwards by purging the land there of it's native population.

Comment: “the bourgeois isn't a group of people and isn't supposed to be hated” well, de facto, the leftists hold hateful speech against the bourgeois

Comment: “You could still frame these as quests for peace and prosperity” the main point is: how? Because as is, in theory, they place the ethnical/ethical purity over the quest of peace and prosperity, and in practice too, because they destroy institutions and kill people (see for instance the terror episode organized by the Montagnards during the French Revolution, or the Nazis)

Comment: @Starckman You need to be careful what you're talking about, whether it's individuals, groups or ideas. They overlap but they aren't identical. E.g the reason for a war stated by generals, politicians or even historians can be very different from the motivation of an individual soldier. Also in terms of left and right, the distinction is between support/acceptance of social hierarchies where the left sees them as a problem and the right sees them as natural/desirable. So a leftist would critique the structure into rulers and ruled, while a rightist would complain about not being the ruler.

Comment: @Starckman 2/ That being said hatred is a strong, blinding, personal emotion, so getting people rallied up against an individual or a scapegoat that is a threat to their peace and prosperity is unfortunately easier than getting them to accept that the current system including their own way of life that they accustomed to is detrimental and harmful to themselves and others. So "left" and "right" in that case are descriptors and should not be confused with group labels, individuals are still capable of supporting causes for various reasons.

Comment: @Starckman 3/ "Because as is, in theory, they place the ethnical/ethical purity over the quest of peace and prosperity" What if ethical/ethnic purity IS considered their way towards peace and prosperity? Like what if people are sold the idea of a zero-sum game where "it's us or them" and where thus sticking together and fighting them becomes imperative to survive as individuals are no match for groups? Or how laws/"ethical purity" are considered the prerequisite for a peaceful coexistence? However despite favoring peace and prosperity, 0-sum games are almost bound to create the opposite.

Comment: @haxor789 I think i tackled your remarks in my answer. Your comments would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Mises was incorrect in believing that individuals universally search "peace and prosperity". I would contend that individuals universally, in part, search peace and prosperity (see other answers and comments).

But there are too many counter-examples where other values are hold also highly, or even come first.

Far-left revolutionary anarchists and communists hold the hate of the bourgeois to drive people into extreme political violence (for seek of ethical purity, or perfect equality), far-right activists hold the hate of other races to drive people into extreme political violence (for sake of ethnical purity), same for the Christians during the Crusades, or the Islamist groups today (for sake of ethical purity). And there are some tribes like the Jivaro, the Yanomami, the Dani, which are extremely violent (for sake of ethical and ethnical purity, I suppose).

One could argue that the revolutionary leftists and the religious extremists promised a perfect land of peace and prosperity (or at least lack of scarcity). The nazis had the idea of "Lebensraum" which is like a promised land for their race, and is supposed to be like a Garden of Eden.

But what we could respond to that is that they first hold other values (ethical and/or ethical purity) as primary over other values (peace and prosperity).

What would be the rational? The rational would be that moral or ethnical purity is not the goal in and for itself pursued by the individual, but a means and an excuse for domination.
Why? Because such societies are hierarchical and oppressive (no individual liberty) societies, in which the individual can seek hierarchical domination by exhibiting a higher morality than others, or a higher devotion to the group than others. The group to which they belong can also develop the belief of its superiority to other groups, and impose itself on other groups via force.

This kind of society do indeed allow people to fulfill a universal motive for domination, but the lack of civil, political, and economic freedom has the consequence of preventing prosperity, and therefore peace (scarcity often leading to physical violence). And at the end, there is even not much domination, because most people live very short and brutish lives.

So I would say that Mises was wrong, individuals search peace and prosperity, AND dominance (or status). And what classical liberals propose is to alleviate that problem by allowing people to fulfill these goals, but in a non violent way, via entrepreneurship and individualism. So classical liberal societies do not need to pretend and force people in being ethically or ethnically pure.

Via entrepreneurship, people can impose themselves, but ‘peacefully’ (being richer than others). This brings material prosperity. And people who do not want to seek dominance can simply not seek social dominance.

Via individualism, people can compete via a lot of different means, instead of via a closed set of values. They can quit and form different little communities indefinitely, instead of getting stuck in one monolithic community. This may prevent individuals from accumulating grievance toward other people.

And finally classical liberals settled the rule of law, which prevents individuals to take charge of injustice retaliation by themself (revenge), often leading to infinite violence.

Comment: Then Marx and French postmodernists crushed this classical liberal revolution by saying that their principles pretending to be defending freedom against domination are themselves tools of domination. But their argumentation is based on a non-falsifiable idea, which is that of "fausse conscience". Also, if individuals speak and act on a "fausse conscience", then these authors also do. Therefore I do not know why I should believe them.

Comment: 1/ So your argument is essentially that "these are not the ONLY motivating factors of an individual". Well there's a concept called "Maslow's hierarchy of needs" essentially survival being foundational, then the individual would try to seek a niche for itself so belonging, love, acceptance, esteem, and then it would try to comprehend its world and optimize itself and later the world itself. Now there's seem to be some criticism about the order of needs and whether it's a hierarchy or how to group it or how they evolve with personal development, but sure there is more than pure survival.

Comment: 2/ Also it's not so much domination that people seek, but "freedom" and "agency", the ability to act and influence one's self and one's environment. Which can in the extreme take the form of domination, but doesn't have to and isn't fully captured with domination. The problem being that if you go towards domination,  this whole thing becomes a zero sum game where freedom for one is only to be achieved at the expense of another. Meaning if they all want individual freedom they will end up in conflict. So you'd be at a crossroad, ignore the rest or find ways to compromise with each other.

Comment: "I would not and did not say that." ??? I mean you did just say that "I would not and did not say that. ", right? The thing is I was somewhat confused where you think Mises is wrong about peace and abundance and so far your argument is that there is more than that. I thought that was just an affirmation of fact, if it isn't than you might want to specify your goal a bit more.

Comment: @haxor789 I would say that peace, prosperity and status are the 3 major motivations of human beings. On status, see the work of psychologist Cameron Anderson. Maybe because domination is also associated to abundance (in material goods, in mates, etc.), and also to peace (if you dominate, maybe could you afford a higher protection?)

Comment: But I suppose that gradually, domination is pursued for its own sake. The brain may have develop neurotransmetters that makes you feel good on high status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147429/discussion-between-haxor789-and-starckman).