# Question about Hegel

Tags: hegel

My professor said Hegel believes that the progress of rationality roots in the contradiction. One of the example is that to Kant's Antinomy, Hegel said we can know two opposite prepositions lead to third one through Aufheben like aufheben morality , you will get the concept family.
In what way does Aufheben transfer them into new preposition?

Comment: i've not read much hegel. what do you mean by 'roots'? begins, works, analysable?

Comment: [What is Hegel's concept of thesis, antithesis and synthesis, in simple terms?](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-hegel-s-concept-of-thesis-antithesis-and-synthesis-in-simple-terms) synthesis –> Aufhebung

Comment: Hegel's model of dialectic is almost always given as a simple threefold process, thesis meets antithesis with tension between resolved by synthesis; however Hegel himself did not do so. He used as the steps: abstract, negative, concrete. See: 'Relation of dialectics, as of Hegel and Marx, toward Enlightenment liberalism' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91665/relation-of-dialectics-as-of-hegel-and-marx-toward-enlightenment-liberalism/91718#91718

Comment: "The test of a first-rate intelligence is the ability to hold two opposed ideas in mind at the same time and still retain the ability to function" -F Scott Fitzgerald.

Answer (score 2):

When something for Hegel is `sublated`, its previous definitive contradictions are preserved within its new form as sublated; and this preservation of what has been overturned or overcome is what enables a thing to be raised to a higher level of development. So it's not that the moral individual loses all of her previous development of her individuality when she finds a partner and forms a new family, but she is seeking her individuality and freedom in another person and in another institution. So the individuality that had been developed in the family she grew up in has been raised and transformed by leaving that family and creating a new one.