# How does the Enlightenment philosophy tackle the asymmetry it has with non-Enlightenment societies/traditions?

Tags: enlightenment, individualism

The Enlightenment thinkers emphasize the individual human being, over his cultural or ethnical affiliation.

This is done by a faith in a universal capacity which is reason, a distrust towards despotism, a pursuit of scientific knowledge, an advocacy for (religious) tolerance, the belief in the *doux commerce* to attain peace between the communities, and of course on a strong commitment to individualism (the individual must be allowed to pursue their own goals).

However, many societies/traditions (including European ones) do not share these values. They emphasize the (ethnical/cultural/religious) group over the individual.

This can create an asymmetry where an (A) Enlightenment-committed society or individual consider as their human-brother the (B) members of these societies/traditions, while (B) in turn do not consider (A) as their human-brother.

Did the Enlightenment thinkers identify this asymmetry their philosophy might create, and how did they propose to tackle it?

Comment: *What you call The Enlightenment, is really the fruits of Christianity* — Tom Holland 《[paraphrased and summarized](https://theopolisinstitute.com/tom-holland-and-the-liberating-power-of-christianity/)》Scrivener's [book](https://amzn.eu/d/e7QJTIe) is a longer summary

Comment: [Rajani Kanth](https://www.waterstones.com/book/breaking-with-the-enlightenment/rajani-kannepalli-kanth/9781573923262) is a complementary view. Also [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/67107/37256)

Comment: @Rushi IMO, emphasizing the "Christian origin or identity of the Enlightenment philosophy" is a big fallacy, because Enlightnement thinkers 1/ where deist, that is, the belief in a supernatural power is dependent on reason, and the human life is independent from any supernatural will 2/ they emphasized the universal over the religiously/ethnical/cultural peculiar.

Comment: One can from a scientific/historical perspective find the influence that Christianity could have had on the Enlightenment philosophy, but giving the primacy of the former over the latter is, IMU, a fallacy. The Enlightenment philosophy has been deeply influenced by the hellenistic civilization, by the roman civilization, by the Renaissance humanists, and of course by the geo-political situation of Europe.

Comment: Yeah that's why I gave two directions: the second is one of (the many) activist-philosophers describing the Enlightenment as actually an endarkenment. James Cone, David Tracey... are some more.  The two together in [argument](https://iai.tv/articles/does-the-enlightenment-need-defending-auid-1149)

Comment: @Rushi Ok but what is the relation to my question?

Comment: It suggests you question the implicit assumptions in your question, eg. (a) the Enlightenment is wholly a good (b) the Enlightenment is a liberation from Christianity (c) the prior state — explicitly called the dark ages, was a worse state [It's fans usually say 'religion' but address mostly Christianity and remain almost entirely cultural Christians while feigning to attack it. And even more than cultural, linguistic: If Arabic is Islamic, Hebrew is Judaic, Sanskrit is Hindu, then like it or not what we're speaking now is Christian]

Comment: @Rushi 1/ No. English is a mix of many languages "English" is named after the Angles, one of the ancient Germanic peoples that migrated to the island of Great Britain. Existing on a dialect continuum with Scots and then most closely related to the Low Saxon and Frisian languages, Modern English is genealogically Germanic."

Comment: 2/ "Although its grammar and core vocabulary are mostly West Germanic, it has borrowed many words from French, which represent approximately 28% of English words, and Latin, which represents about 28%,[6] and some grammar and core vocabulary from Old Norse, a North Germanic language.[7][8][9] Speakers of English are called Anglophones. " Wikipedia

Comment: "It's fans usually say 'religion' but address mostly Christianity and remain almost entirely cultural Christians while feigning to attack it." What does "cultural Christian" even mean? Europe and the US have a history which is marked in part by Cristianity, but not only, far from it. "feigning to attack it." well, it is hard to respond to this affirmation, because it is blurred and speculative. I feel your view is extremely biased, everything being seen from the lense of religion only, religion being used as a false nose for race.

Comment: *cultural Christian* See this [YT comment by Barnestm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xi0BdLgQmPw&lc=UgzTgxwTH1v45y_vzW94AaABAg). Interestingly he dichotomizes 'cultural' vs 'believing' Christian showing that he remains firmly a cultural Christian: its only in Christianity that 'faith' and 'religion' are synonymous — one of the zillion indicators that English is Christian

Comment: The result that emerged from Game Theory is that the only stable equilibrium of cooperation is "tit for tat" - cooperate with cooperators and punish or rebuke defectors. If this fails, the only possible strategy is to never cooperate at all. So, it has nothing to do with any ideas or reasons, it is just math.

Answer (score 4):

Enlightenment thinkers were not unaware of the potential for asymmetry or conflict with non-Enlightenment societies. Indeed, many of them engaged deeply with the issue. They sought to reconcile these differences in a variety of ways.

**1. Universalism of Reason:**

Enlightenment thinkers posited that reason was a universal capacity, inherent in all human beings regardless of their cultural or societal background. Philosophers like Immanuel Kant argued that this faculty of reason could bridge the gap between different societies and traditions. Even if a society did not currently embrace Enlightenment values, the potential was always there, since reason was inherent in every individual.

**2. Cultural Relativism and Tolerance:**

Some Enlightenment thinkers advocated for the idea of cultural relativism, which suggests that no culture is superior to another and that every culture has its own intrinsic value. This perspective respects the diversity of cultures and promotes tolerance. Voltaire, for example, advocated for religious tolerance and respect for all cultures, even as he was a sharp critic of organized religion. This might not eliminate the asymmetry, but it could mitigate potential conflict.

**3. Education and Progress:**

Many Enlightenment thinkers believed in the power of education to spread Enlightenment ideals. They believed that through education, societies could progress and eventually adopt Enlightenment values. This perspective is evident in the work of thinkers like Rousseau and Diderot. The Encyclopédie, led by Diderot, was a major endeavor to disseminate knowledge and Enlightenment values across Europe and beyond.

**4. Trade and Commerce:**

Enlightenment thinkers also believed that trade and commerce could act as social levellers, creating common ground between different societies. Adam Smith, the father of modern economics, argued that the invisible hand of the market could harmonize the interests of individuals and societies, potentially reducing conflict and promoting understanding.

However the Enlightenment thinkers did not entirely resolve the asymmetry with non-Enlightenment societies. Their belief in the universality of reason and the potential for all societies to progress towards Enlightenment values has been criticized as Eurocentric or even imperialistic. Moreover, the Enlightenment itself was not a monolithic movement, and different thinkers proposed different solutions to this problem.

Comment: "3. Education and Progress:" But how to enact this? I mean, the societies who do not recognize the Enlightenment ideas will no allow them to be taught!

Comment: Same for "2. Cultural Relativism and Tolerance". Many non-Enlightenment societies/traditions do not hold "cultural relativism" and "tolerance" as positive values, on the contrary. So an Enlightenment person might be tolerant to them, but this tolerance will not be reciprocal (something Diderot alludes to in his *Supplément au Voyage de Bougainville*)

Comment: Re: reason - the Game Theory result in my comment to the question should be discoverable by people with any sort of ideas and beliefs. Reasonable people would then find through interaction with others that their cherished beliefs are not operative of anything in the world and they would discard those beliefs. Perhaps this is a sort of post-Enlightenment thinking? I call it common sense, but in many places it is rare.